# SslSocket not writing on underlying socket

Tags: java, ssl, tls1.2

i created an SslSocket from an existing connected server socket.

```
SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(socket, socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress(), socket.getPort(), false);
```

after this step the ssl handshake is successful.

when i write to the `sslSocket` , i am able to see logs `(-Djavax.net.debug=all)` showing that `SslEngine` is doing the encryption, as it prints the bytes before encryption

```
 Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 276
 0000: 01 00 01 14 C0 00 01 10   00 00 00 04 28 60 00 02
 ....
 WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 300
```

but it doesn't write any data to socket. there are no encrypted bytes printed in logs also. seems it is stuck somewhere after printing `WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 300`. I checked with WireShark, there are no bytes transferred.

But the same `sslSocket` was able to do handshake and write to socket during handshake phase.

Similarly, i have another case where a connected client socket is converted to sslSocket. In that case, it works fine after handshake, and is able to send encrypted data onto socket.

Not sure why it doesn't work in the server case after handshake.

Comment: Is the peer actually receiving? The write could be blocked by closure of the receive window.

Comment: as per wireshark, nothing is being sent (after handshake).

Comment: I know it's obvious but did you flush your stream?

Comment: i checked the ssl socket code, `outputstream.flush` is invoked internally. when i used client side sslSocket, i didnt invoke `flush` and it worked.

Comment: on further debugging, it is releaved that the `socket.getOutputStream().write(byes)` actually blocks on a lock. since the socket is `selectable socket` there is a `blockinglock` which is already aquired by the read thread. the read thread acquires the lock and goes into blocking `read()`. so cannot write :(